# How to display a BLOB image back as an image without using Content-Type in php

Tags: php, sql, image, blob

I stored an image in a database using a `BLOB` type and i want to display the image on a page without using `Content-Type:image/jpeg`. I have searched and found this code `<img src='data:image/jpeg;<?php echo base64,base64_decode($imageData)?>'>` but it doesn't work it just prints a lot of texts and symbols. I know i can display the image using a separate page but i don't want to do that, So is there any other solution?

Comment: base64_encode instead of decode should wok better. You need the image data in base64 encoding.

Comment: I have change it to base64_encode and works great thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $imageData ).'"/>';
```

Comment: I have tried it but prints out a corrupted image icon

Comment: $imageData is the value you are directly fetching from database right?

Comment: Yes i am directly fetching it

Comment: Can you cross check whether the image stored in database is corrupted or not?

Comment: I have added a header like this header('Content-Type:image/jpeg') to the page and the image displays correctly the image is not corrupted

Comment: @surafel you probably need to specify the height and width of the image.

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src='data:image/jpeg;base64,<?php echo $imageData?>'>
```

Try this. You don't need to decode the base64 string if you are doing like this. Provided, `$imageData` is already Base64 encoded.